# javascript comparing two array with different objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to compare arrays

```
var maps1= [{name: triangle, value: 1},{name: square, value: 2}];
var maps2= [triangle,rectangle];
```

i want to compare these both arrays, if object of map2 matches with objects of map1 then i need to get the value of map1, like in the above exmaple triangle matches and i want to get the value of triangle.

```
  function identical (arr1, arr2) {

        if(arr1.length != arr2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        var exists = arr1.length;
        for(var i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
            for(var j =0; j<arr2.length ; j++) {
                if(Object.keys(arr1[i]).equals(Object.keys(arr2[j]))) {
                   exists--;
                }
            }
        }

        return !exists;
    }
```

Comment: what is the value of `triangle`?? it is it self a value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o8t22ert/1/ Perhaps something like that? (check javascript console for output), despite it works there specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var map1= [{name: 'triangle', value: '1'},{name: 'square', value: '2'}];
var map2= ['triangle','rectangle'];
var result=[];
for(i=0; i<map2.length; i++){
    var comp= map2[i];
    for(j=0; j<map1.length; j++){
        if(map1[j].hasOwnProperty('name')){
            if(map1[j].name == comp){
               result.push(map1[j]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hg2790/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function com(arr1, arr2){
   return arr1.filter(function(v){
    if(arr2.indexOf(v.name) !== -1) return true;
   })

}
```

Comment: You _do_ realize that's just a `return arr2.indexOf(v.name) !== -1;` in the function right?

Comment: tested and worked with the value outside of fn, what am i missing?